# How to implement role-based authorization in WPF application calling database through WCF services?

Tags: c#, wpf, membership-provider, roleprovider, iprincipal

I have a WCF service that send queries to a database using stored procedure. The WCF services are called with a WPF application where role-based authorization is implemented with IIdentity and IPrincipal. 
I want to use this role-based security to protect the WCF services, but I don't know how to proceed.

It's a bit of a mess in my head :) I read about Membership, RoleProvider... but don't really understand the difference and in what case to use these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Role Provider is appropriate in this situation.

Information on How to set it up with WCF can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647040.aspx